# What to replace deprecated Class 'Zend_Rest_Client' with in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, model, rest-api, zend-framework, http-request

A module I'm maintaining is not working on Magento 2.3 since Magento apparently deprecated Class 'Zend_Rest_Client' . I don't see any replacement Client listed in their documentation, so I'm a bit confused on which class I should be extending now.

This is my class on line 5:

```
class Client extends \Zend_Rest_Client
```

This is the error thrown in Magento 2.3:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Rest_Client' not found in
>   /m23/app/code/Maurisource/Module/Model/Rest/Client.php on line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in that Magento deprecated the Zend_Rest module and a bunch of others. You can find a full list here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/

With replacements, as far as I am aware there is no direct replacement for it.

Instead, if we are trying to modify/extend the client, then we case use the `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client` class as the base.

Or if we are trying to use the client to make requests with we can inject one of the following blocks, examples of usage here: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/485

- `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient`
- `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl`
- `\Zend_Http_Client`